# Translate labels in CP with Craft CMS 3

Tags: craft3, localization, control-panel

I was wondering if it was possible to translate the labels, like "Singles","Entries" in the CP

I know it's possible with Craft 2, but I didn't find with Craft 3.

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to do. You can do it via [Static Translations](https://t.co/ZzaIJylmP3). Just create `translations/en-US/app.php` (or whatever your site language is), and do the mapping there as per: https://twitter.com/nystudio107/status/1045963809956012032

Comment: Thank's @andrew.welch !